# Sitecore Multiple Site Set up..host names

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, sitecore

So I am trying to set up in sitecore to handle multi site set up with two different host headers. But no matter what I do it always reverts to default site with either host header.

So At the moment my default is in my web config as follows :

```
<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/Home Page" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" hostname="localhost" loginPage="/Account/SourceLoginRouter" />
```

And the new one I am trying to add in then

```
<site name="SmartEmea" hostName="secondSite" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/SmartEmea" startItem="/Home" database="master" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" language="nl-NL" customLinkManager="ValtechLinkManager"/>
```

And my host file is as follows

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       secondSite
```

But no matter what it always reverts to website and its `rootpath` of `/sitecore/content`

Comment: A note on multisite -- When generating internal links, keep an eye out on your cross-site links. I need to have SiteResolving on in my UrlOptions I'm feeding to my LinkProvider (http://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/using-cross-site-links-dynamic-links/) otherwise I get long, incorrect, internal URLs even with the SiteResolving turned on in the web.config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must make sure the "website" `<site ... />` node is LAST of all of the configured sites. This "website" node acts as a catch-all. As a request come in, it goes down the `<site ... />` nodes and matches against each `hostName` until it find a site to run. If you have "website" first, it will just run since it catches on any host.

E.g.

```
<site name="SmartEmea" hostName="secondSite" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content/SmartEmea" startItem="/Home" database="master" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" language="nl-NL" customLinkManager="ValtechLinkManager"/>
<site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/Home Page" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" hostname="localhost" loginPage="/Account/SourceLoginRouter" />
```